# Insert Live Broadcasts sometimes has 403 "Request is not authorized" error

Tags: youtube-livestreaming-api

My access token is validate and can use it to list Live Broadcasts , but when I multiple insert Live Broadcasts, return error as below,

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.liveBroadcast",
    "reason": "insufficientLivePermissions",
    "message": "Request is not authorized",
    "extendedHelp": "https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/insert#auth_required"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Request is not authorized"
 }
}
```

Testing flow
Get new Access token through Google Client APIs (NodeJS)
List LiveBroadcasts ,success get result
Insert single LiveBroadcasts, sucess insert
Insert single LiveBroadcasts again, success insert
Using multiple insert 5 LiveBroadcasts, get Error

```
{ domain: 'youtube.liveBroadcast',
   reason: 'insufficientLivePermissions',
   message: 'Request is not authorized',
              extendedHelp: 'https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/insert#auth_required' }
```

List LiveBroadcasts again , success get result
Insert single LiveBroadcasts, get Error (403 Request is not authorizd)
Using YouTube Live Stream API demo page , insert Live Broadcast, get Error(403 Request is not authorized)

Issue :
I have validate access token and can execute List LiveBroadcasts successful , but why getting error in insert LiveBroadcasts ? 
I have checked API Quota , it is enough
I have checked client_secret , it is correct
I have checked access token , it is validate
Does YouTube Live Stream API have new limitation or constrains ?

Comment: I got this also, happened when doing 19 live broadcast a day.